# How to enable b2b request quote button in hybris 6.3

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I installed hybris 6.3 version but after installation when i opened site then it is not showing request quote button while checkout so please help me how to enable that.

Comment: Might be issue with role permissions

Comment: Have you followed all steps of this doc : https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/2da1f64921a34302b839f7ae806bfed8.html?

Answer (score -2):

Quote requests in 6.3 are moved from b2b accelerator to the core commerce accelerator. Features are quite considerably enhanced; you'll want to review documentation.